# Exporting xml file from selecting one by one data in database in OSB

Tags: middleware, osb

Using JDeveloper in order to create and manage Oracle Service Bus 12c resources, I want to export the xml  file format form selecting one by one data in database.

My first thought was to search if JDeveloper provides such way or attempt do this programmatically, yet my search on this has not given me any information of how-to.

Is there any way of doing this?Please kindly answer.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? Export OSB project offline: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/osb/develop/GUID-097674FB-B943-4124-B85B-B29BE8FCBF00.htm#OSBDV1971

Comment: Do you want to fetch xml data from database and include those xml's into service response?

Comment: Yes,I want to select data from database and that selected output data will be shown with xml format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the data from database in xml format,use a db adapter in the osb project..DB adapter returns the data retrieved from database as xml.